# Spring Boot Maven Plugin – Exclude all dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my current project I'm using spring boot i want to exclude all dependencies.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>a.b.testClass</mainClass>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
          <excludeArtifactIds>*</excludeArtifactIds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you do that then it won't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do that... That basically beats the purpose of even using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly solution that seems to work is to put includes with not existing artifact:

```
<configuration>
    <layout>ZIP</layout>
    <includes>
        <include>
            <groupId>abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        </include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

Works on version 1.3.3 but there is not guarantee it won't change in next versions.

Or, you can package everything yourself, there are instructions for ant:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-build-an-executable-archive-with-ant
that can give you list of steps that you need to apply in maven. So:

1. Include Main Class and Start Class in manifest:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

       <configuration>
           <archive>
               <manifest>
                   <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher</mainClass>
               </manifest>
               <manifestEntries>
                   <Start-Class>your.package.YourMainClass</Start-Class>
               </manifestEntries>
           </archive>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Skip adding dependencies in lib directory.
3. Add spring boot loader classes to the root: First you need dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Then you need to unpack it:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>process-sources</phase>

               <goals>
                   <goal>unpack</goal>
               </goals>

               <configuration>
                   <artifactItems>
                       <artifactItem>
                           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                           <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                       </artifactItem>
                   </artifactItems>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   There might be a better way to put loader classes in root, but this works ok for my project.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one.

```
<configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
```